# How to convert masks generated by rasterio to channel last mask

Tags: image, numpy, digital-image-processing, rasterio, machine-learning

The problem is about using rasterio to generate mask from GeoJSON file which contains geographic coordinates.

The function that I used is from:

```
from rasterio.tools.mask import mask
with rasterio.open(img_path) as src:
        img_mask, out_transform = mask(src, [poly], crop = False)
```

The shape of the mask that I generated is:

(4, 256, 256)

I converted this mask to (256,256) black and white image by taking the first channel of the mask. I used for loop to do this process couple times, and then I appended all the (256,256) masks into a list. I tried to use np.stack to convert the list to a numpy array with dimension (256,256,?). However, I got an array with dimension (?,256,256). I tried to set axis=-1; however, the image shape becomes (256,?) rather than (256,256).

Is there any method that can convert the channel first array to a channel last array with numpy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want to reorder your array axes:

```
array.transpose((1, 2, 0))
```

This will order the dimensions 0,1,2 (?,256,256) to 1,2,0 (256,256,?). Also take a look at the examples here: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.moveaxis.html

Comment: Thank you so much. I just figured out where the error happens, and it is also a way to do that. I finally use np.stack with axis=-1, and it also solved the problem. The problem is that I did some mistake in indexing the dimension.